# Get the title of html document using xslt

Tags: xslt, saxon

I am unable to get the value of head/title element as follow.

## xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    version="2.0" >

 <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="h:title">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>  
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
.AlignLeft { text-align: left; }
.AlignCenter { text-align: center; }
.AlignRight { text-align: right; }
</style>
<title>Doc title</title>
</head>
<body>
    body
</body>
</html> 


java -jar saxon9he.jar -xsl:style.xsl -s:test.html
```

output:

```
.AlignLeft { text-align: left; }
.AlignCenter { text-align: center; }
.AlignRight { text-align: right; }
Doc title
    body
```

expected output:

```
 Doc title
```

Comment: Can you say what your expected output in this case? The `title` is actually appearing, but I am guessing you don't want the `style` or `body` to be shown either? Thanks!

Comment: yes I only expected `title` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you are experiencing is because of XSLT's [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule). These are apply when XSLT is looking for a template to match a node, but one doesn't appear in your XSLT.

At the moment, the XSLT will look for templates matching `style` and `body` but find none, and so the built-in templates apply and will ultimately output text.

What you could do, is explicitly tell XSLT to select only the `title` like so:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="/h:html/h:head/h:title"/>  
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, add a template that overrides the built-in template that stops any text being output:

```
 <xsl:template match="text()" />
```

Adding either of these templates to your existing XSLT should work.